# Type error with dictionary object

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, dictionary, devexpress

I'm getting the following error when I try to click a button on my form after changing the quantity value. The key and quantity gets properly set (as I can see during debugging).

**I don't know why I'm getting the error....**

```
The value "1" is not of type "System.Int32" and cannot be used in this generic collection.
Parameter name: value
```

I checked on the web for this message, but nothing that I read deciphers what is wrong.

I have the dictionary object set up as follows. Note that I try changing the type to string, string and the same message appears (above) except instead of `"System.Int32"`, `"System.String"`.

```
PageData["ClientSelectedQtyRows"] = new Dictionary<string, Int32>();
```

Here is my JS that fires when I change my quantity value on the screen:

```
function UpdateQtySelection(key, qty) {
            if (key) {
                var dict = PageDataClient.Get("ClientSelectedQtyRows");
                dict[key] = qty;
                PageDataClient.Set("ClientSelectedQtyRows", dict);
            }
        }
```

During debugging, the dictionary object contains the proper values after I change the quantity.

```
?dict[key]
1

?PageDataClient.Get("ClientSelectedQtyRows")
{...}
    [prototype]: {...}
    [41769]: 1
    [prototype]: []
```

The markup for the Print button is as follows:

```
<td style="padding-right: 10px;">
                                    <dx:ASPxButton ID="btnPrint" Text="Print" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="btnPrintClient" CausesValidation="false" ValidationGroup="CS" Theme="PlasticBlue" AutoPostBack="false" Enabled="false">
                                        <ClientSideEvents Click="function (s,e) { PerformCallback('1:'); btnPrintClient.disabled = true; btnSearchClient.disabled = true; }" />
                                    </dx:ASPxButton>
                                </td>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not adding the `string` value `1` rather than the integer 1?

Comment: As you can see in my debugging values, the key is 41769 and its value is 1, not "1".

Comment: Change it to `dict[key] = parseInt(qty, 10);` just to be sure

Comment: I modified the code as you suggested and during debugging, got the exact same values and the message still comes up.... I just don't get this simple error that is giving me a huge headache :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the ASPXHiddenField does not support an integer in a dictionary object, I made it into a .

During the JS function, I was missing one thing to do.

I changed the value from:

dict[key] = parseInt(qty, 10);

to

dict[key] = qty.toString();

and that solved the issue...